# How do i show an attribute of an object, rather than the object itself, in an accessor field in django-tables2?

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have a table of `Compounds` with a `name` field, which is linked to another table called `Names`.

When I render a table with django-tables2, it's showing up just fine except for the fact that it doesn't say `aspirin` in the `name` column, it says `Name object`.

`models.py`:

```
class Compound(models.Model):

    drug_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    drug_name = models.ForeignKey(Name, db_column='drug_name', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # for flagging problematic data
    flag_id = models.ForeignKey(Flag, db_column='flag_id', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # is a cocktail
    is_combination = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'compounds'
```

`tables.py`:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from .models import Compound

class FimTable(tables.Table):

    drug_name = tables.Column(accessor='name.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Compound
        attrs = {'class': 'paleblue table table-condensed table-vertical-center'}
        fields = ('drug_id', 'drug_name')
        sequence = ('drug_id', 'drug_name')
        order_by = ('drug_id')
```

`views.py`:

```
@csrf_protect
@login_required  # redirects to login page if user.is_active is false
def render_fim_table(request):

    table = FimTable(Compound.objects.all())

    table.paginate(page=request.GET.get('page', 1), per_page=20)

    response = render(request, 'fim_table.html', {'table': table})
    return response
```

Result:

[image: The resulting table. Notice that it says "Name Object" instead of the name itself.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define the `__str__` method on the Name object.

```
class Name(models.Model):
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: THANK YOU. Marking as the correct answer once it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use...

```
class Name(model.Model):
      ...
      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.name
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could elaborate on the difference between `__str__` and `__unicode__` and why one would use one or the other.